# Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change. when I run meteor project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have meteor 1.6 project. and node version 8.8.1.
But I get this error, I can't find reason.

E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1>set TOOL_NODE_FLAGS=--max-old-space-size=3300

```
E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1>set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1>meteor
[[[[[ ~\E\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1 ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> A patch (Meteor 1.6.1.4) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20220509-09:14:56.813(9)? (STDERR) E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:89
W20220509-09:14:56.845(9)? (STDERR)                                     return fn.apply(this, arguments);
W20220509-09:14:56.846(9)? (STDERR)                                               ^
W20220509-09:14:56.846(9)? (STDERR)
W20220509-09:14:56.847(9)? (STDERR) Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\node_modules'
W20220509-09:14:56.847(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1672:17)
W20220509-09:14:56.848(9)? (STDERR)     at toRealPath (module.js:154:13)
W20220509-09:14:56.848(9)? (STDERR)     at tryFile (module.js:150:22)
W20220509-09:14:56.848(9)? (STDERR)     at tryExtensions (module.js:162:22)
W20220509-09:14:56.849(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:215:20)
W20220509-09:14:56.849(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:511:25)
W20220509-09:14:56.849(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
W20220509-09:14:56.850(9)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
W20220509-09:14:56.850(9)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
W20220509-09:14:56.851(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:283:20)
=> Exited with code: 1
W20220509-09:15:02.504(9)? (STDERR) E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:89
W20220509-09:15:02.505(9)? (STDERR)                                     return fn.apply(this, arguments);
W20220509-09:15:02.505(9)? (STDERR)                                               ^
W20220509-09:15:02.505(9)? (STDERR)
W20220509-09:15:02.506(9)? (STDERR) Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\node_modules'
W20220509-09:15:02.506(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1672:17)
W20220509-09:15:02.507(9)? (STDERR)     at toRealPath (module.js:154:13)
W20220509-09:15:02.507(9)? (STDERR)     at tryFile (module.js:150:22)
W20220509-09:15:02.507(9)? (STDERR)     at tryExtensions (module.js:162:22)
W20220509-09:15:02.508(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:215:20)
W20220509-09:15:02.508(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:511:25)
W20220509-09:15:02.509(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
W20220509-09:15:02.509(9)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
W20220509-09:15:02.509(9)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
W20220509-09:15:02.510(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:283:20)
=> Exited with code: 1
W20220509-09:15:07.762(9)? (STDERR) E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\node_modules\fibers\fibers.js:89
W20220509-09:15:07.763(9)? (STDERR)                                     return fn.apply(this, arguments);
W20220509-09:15:07.764(9)? (STDERR)                                               ^
W20220509-09:15:07.764(9)? (STDERR)
W20220509-09:15:07.765(9)? (STDERR) Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\node_modules'
W20220509-09:15:07.765(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1672:17)
W20220509-09:15:07.765(9)? (STDERR)     at toRealPath (module.js:154:13)
W20220509-09:15:07.766(9)? (STDERR)     at tryFile (module.js:150:22)
W20220509-09:15:07.766(9)? (STDERR)     at tryExtensions (module.js:162:22)
W20220509-09:15:07.767(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:215:20)
W20220509-09:15:07.767(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:511:25)
W20220509-09:15:07.767(9)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
W20220509-09:15:07.768(9)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
W20220509-09:15:07.768(9)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
W20220509-09:15:07.768(9)? (STDERR)     at Object.require (E:\Web\Meteor\vs1project_vs1\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:283:20)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some file permissions got messed up, maybe you ran it as root once? Just delete `.meteor\local\build` and restart `meteor`.

Comment: I follow, but I get same error. I run it as admin. unfortunately the result is same.